# Predict the future value using regression model in python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

Here I have one dataset from csv file .I want to predict the next value with the time period. Can we use nonlinear regression model to predict the value for next time period or is there any regression model can we use to predict the value?
Any suggestion please?

Here I upload the subset of my original dataset.

```js
Time g p c y
0:13:50 85 0 0 85
0:15:25 0 0 50 90
0:16:25 135 0 0 135
0:18:00 0 0 2 130
0:19:00 63 0 0 ?
```

My original graph ,
[image]

After predicting the graph,
[image]

Comment: You can convert the time to a numeric value such as 1:30:00 to 1.5 (hours) - I have done this in the past to get "time since start" as a number for my regression software. You might also visually inspect scatterplots of all variables vs. "y" to determine if any obvious data transform or non-linear relationship is apparent, that is usually fast and sometimes helps.

Comment: @ James Phillips I convert the time using this code; data['Time'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Time']).astype(np.int64)//10**9)%86400 . After that I tried to predict next value using tensorflow. But graph is not plotting with the time and predict values display as predict label (0.5096755). Here I upload the two graphs for refer and can you please suggest me any examples related to my matter?

Comment: I suggest adding the tag "tensorflow" to the question.

Comment: @James Phillips I tagged  the tensorflow.

Comment: @awa It sounds like you not longer have a "how do I represent time" problem. If you are looking for regression examples, here are some - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/regression_examples. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: No I'm stuck with the representing the time in graph. I want to predict next value with time and prediction will continue after one hour one hour. Could you please suggest me any options to solve this matter? @ iga